# how to insert data from jtable to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

I want to insert jtable multiple rows data into mysql database on save button click. It gives some error....

This is my code...

```
package my.bill;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax .swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class bill extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form bill
     */
    Object[][] data=null;
    String[] columnNames = new String[2];

   /*static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
   //static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "root";*/



    public bill() {
        initComponents();
        CurrentDate();

           }

    public void CurrentDate(){
    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
    int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Date.setText(day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Date = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        netprofit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        netsum = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        save = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Date");

        Date.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"", null, null, null, null, null},
                {"", null, null, null, "", null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Job No", "Item", "Billed Amount", "Parts cost", "Net Profit", "Percentage"
            }
        ));
        jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jTable1.setRowHeight(20);
        jTable1.setRowMargin(2);
        jTable1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTable1.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                jTable1InputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Job No");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Item");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("Billed Amount");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setHeaderValue("Parts cost");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setHeaderValue("Net Profit");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setHeaderValue("Percentage");
        }

        netprofit.setText("Total Profit");
        netprofit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                netprofitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        save.setText("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(114, 114, 114)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(350, 350, 350)
                        .addComponent(netprofit)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(netsum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(221, 221, 221)
                        .addComponent(save)))
                .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(netprofit)
                    .addComponent(netsum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(save)
                .addContainerGap(32, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        Date.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("date");
        save.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("save");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        



    private void DateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                    

    private void netprofitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                         

    private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        Connection conn = null;

   Statement stmt = null;

        int count=jTable1.getRowCount();
        int col=jTable1.getColumnCount();
       String jobno[] =new String[count]; // name is array and index 4 means no. of row 
        String item[]=new String[count]; 
        String bill[] =new String[count]; // name is array and index 4 means no. of row 
         String part[]=new  String[count]; 
       String profit[] =new  String[count]; // name is array and index 4 means no. of row 
       String percent[]=new  String[count]; 

       for(int i=0;i<=count;i++) 
 {
     for(int j=0;j<=col;j++)
     {
 no[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString(); // it get value from 0 row and 0 column
it[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
 amount[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
 p[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
 cost[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
s[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();


        try{

            String sql="INSERT INTO m (no,it,amount,cost,sell,p,date) VALUES('"+no[i]+"','"+it[i]+"','"+amount[i]+"','"+p[i]+"','"+cost[i]+"','"+s[i]+"','"+Date.getText()+"')";
          //  stmt.execute(sql);
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //stmt.execute(sql);
            /*PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, "");
            ps.setString(2, "");
            ps.setString(3, "");
            ps.setString(4, "");
            ps.setString(5, "");
            ps.setString(6, "");
            ps.setString(7,Date.getText());
            ps.execute();*/

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"saved");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
 }
    }                                    

    private void jTable1InputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(bill.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

         Connection conn = null;

   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       //Class.forName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb", "root", "root");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();


   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
     // se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
     // e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   //System.out.println("Goodbye!");

        //int r=jTable1.selectedrow;
        //jTable1.getValue(3,3);
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new bill().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField Date;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JButton netprofit;
    private javax.swing.JTextField netsum;
    private javax.swing.JButton save;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

how i insert the multiple rows data into mysql database....
Please help....

Comment: show us the stacktrace,post only relevant codes,post the table schema

Comment: i am beginner in java so i create this code

Comment: why you are wrting 2 times stmt.execute(sql);
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: remove uncessary codes and post the stacktrace

Comment: when save button clicked it shows  java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

From what it looks like, you are not even initializing the `connection` and `statement` under the saveActionPerformed method, you are setting them to NULL.

```
private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        Connection conn = null;

   Statement stmt = null;
```

In your main method however you are indeed initializing them..

```
try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       //Class.forName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb", "root", "root");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();


   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
```

You need to either remove the code where you set them to NULL or add the same code directly afterwards and remember you need to put the code INSIDE your try and catch block.

Something like this:

```
try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //Class.forName("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganpatidb", "root", "root");
    //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating database...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    int count=jTable1.getRowCount();
    int col=jTable1.getColumnCount();
    String jobno[] =new String[count];
    // name is array and index 4 means no. of row
    String item[]=new String[count];
    String bill[] =new String[count];
    // name is array and index 4 means no. of row
    String part[]=new String[count];
    String profit[] =new String[count];
    // name is array and index 4 means no. of row
    String percent[]=new String[count];
    for(int i=0;
    i&lt;
    =count;
    i++)   {
        for(int j=0;
        j&lt;
        =col;
        j++)  {
            no[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            // it get value from 0 row and 0 columN
            it[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            amount[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            p[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            cost[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            s[i]=jTable1.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            try{
                String sql="INSERT INTO m (no,it,amount,cost,sell,p,date) VALUES('"+no[i]+"','"+it[i]+"','"+amount[i]+"','"+p[i]+"','"+cost[i]+"','"+s[i]+"','"+Date.getText()+"')";
                stmt.execute(sql);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"saved");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)  stmt.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se2){
            }
            // nothing we can do
            try{
                if(conn!=null)  conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se){
                //se.printStackTrace();
            }
            //end finally try
        }
        //end try
```

Comment: @user3751867 I am afraid that you're iterating over the table values incorrectly, this code provides a working example of how to insert a value into the database. The part where you iterate over the table is another question, which shouldn't be discussed here.